# How to avoid duplicate values from the contacts database while usingContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI?

Tags: android, contacts, android-cursorloader

I am using the following query to fetch the list of contacts.

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    String SELECTION = String.format("%s =\'1\' AND length(\"%s, \") > 0",
            ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY);

    return new CursorLoader(context,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, // URI
            ContactProfile.CONTACT_PROJECTION, // projection fields
            SELECTION, // the selection criteria
            null, // the selection args
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY
                    + " COLLATE NOCASE ASC" // case insensitive sort order
    );
}
```

But I am getting duplicate values on phone with multiple accounts. How to avoid this duplicate values

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use "distinct" when query using CursorLoader.
Pass account param for the query selection, or remove duplicates when use the returned cursor.